# SignalR 2.0 - Accessing hub without proxy

Tags: javascript, asp.net, proxy, signalr

with the following html/js code I am able to successfully call my signalR 2.0 hub if html/js and hub resides on the same server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test SignalR 2.0</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        background-color: #99CCFF;
        border: thick solid #808080;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" size=100 id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
</div>
<ul id="discussion"></ul>
<!--Script references. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //Instanciating Hub-Class
        var srv = $.connection.pvHub;

        // Definition of function called by HUB (Server)
        srv.client.receiveData = function (message) {
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            $('#discussion').append('<ul>' + encodedMsg + '</ul><br>');
        };

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // call HUB function (on Server)
                srv.server.getBnoData($('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Now I am trying to call the hub with the same html/js file located on a client. But no success.
I think, there are some issues with the hub proxy and the URL of my hub on instantiating the connection and start it. But strictly speaking no idea how to resolve this.

Any idea?

thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to enable Cross Domain support. Read this:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain

Also, in case you have already set it up, you have to update your client code to point at the right endpoint, by updating the `/signalr/hubs` relative address to an absolute one, and by specifying a valid absolute address for `$.connection.hub.url`. Something like:

```
<script src="http://foo.com/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>

    ...
    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://foo.com/signalr';
    ...

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so far. But first line in my code instanciates my "pvHub". How do I have to instanciate before this line the "connection" that I am able to set "connection.hub.url="
Thx in advance.

Comment: Specify the url exactly the way I showed, and do that just before the line where you start the connection

Comment: Thanks a lot. After setting CORS on the server as well all runs perfect!